# Lie group cohomology with coefficients in Lie algebra

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology, intuition, lie-algebra-cohomology

I'm looking for a reference, and basic results, about Lie algebra as modules over a Lie group (with the adjoint representation), from the point of view of cohomology. Links with the Lie algebra cohomology itself are welcome.

In case it is not clear what I'm asking, here is an example. An invariant polynomial is a map from a Lie algebra $A$ to another algebra or module (in the simplest case, $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$) which is well-defined on the conjugacy classes, i.e. $f(gxg^{-1})=f(x)$ for any $x$ in $L$ and $g$ in $G$. What is its homological interpretation?

(Please feel free to edit the question and the tags appropriately.)